# Change AssemblyName of csproj file in Azure Pipeline via powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-pipelines, csproj, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-yaml

trying to change the AssemblyName of an .Net project file inside Azure Pipeline.
Reason is to have a special name of the process.
Would like to use PowerShell for this.
I tried this:

```
 - task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      [xml]$xml =(gc "src/WaWiXPO/WaWiXPO.csproj")
      Write-Host $xml.Project.PropertyGroup[0].AssemblyName
      $xml.Project.PropertyGroup[0].AssemblyName = "WaWiDEV"
      $xml.Save("WaWiXPO.csproj")
```

Locally it is working fine, but in the pipeline, it does no change.
No error message.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of it, you need to pass the full path to the call to Save:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $path = "src/WaWiXPO/WaWiXPO.csproj"
      [xml]$xml =(gc $path)
      Write-Host $xml.Project.PropertyGroup[0].AssemblyName
      $xml.Project.PropertyGroup[0].AssemblyName = "WaWiDEV"
      $xml.Save($path)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this quick and precise answer.